# What happens when we set useLegacyDatetimeCode to false in JDBC connection object

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timestamp, mysql-5.7

Also should we use this field in JDBC connection object in case we upgrade to mysql-connector-java version: 8?

Comment: I suggest linking to documentation for the feature at question here.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-properties-changed.html), the property `useLegacyDatetimeCode` has been dropped when going from Connector/J 5.1 to 8.0.

Comment: But what if we want to handle timezone conversion between client and server? How can we do that in mysql-connector-java 8.0?

Comment: @AishwerSharma I have written many Answers on that topic, as has [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) So search Stack Overflow. Use only *java.time*, always pass the otherwise optional time zone arguments, and you’ll be coding in such a manner as to never care about the current default time zone on either client or server. If after searching thoroughly you still have a question, post a new Question here. Search for classes Instant, OffsetDateTime, ZonedDateTime, LocalDateTime, LocalDate, LocalTime, ZoneId, ZoneOffset. Never use Date or Calendar or Timestamp classes.